# Removing menu screen on game launch

Tags: python, kivy

I'm developing a simple shooter game with Kivy. I'm at the point where
I'm launching new game from the game menu. However the program behaves strangely and I don't know why. When I click on "start" the game launches but the menu screen won't go away. It moves up instead.

I've tried to fiddle with `self.remove_widget(sm)` but that had no effect.

I recorded the behaviour here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1R-JV74w4VDThOvjf9Xhm7w6WV8rWtEgZ for you to see.

Here's my code:

kv file:

```
        Label:
            text: 'menu'
            font_name: "fonts/Alexis Bold.ttf"
            font_size: 30
            color: 0, 1, 0, 1

        Button:
            text: 'start game'
            on_press: app.launch_game()
        Button:
            text: 'highest score'
            on_release: 
        Button:
            text: 'credits'
            on_release: app.root.current = 'credits'
```

Python code:

```
class GameApp(App):

    sm = ScreenManager()
    sm.add_widget(Game_Menu(name='menu'))
    sm.add_widget(Credits_Screen(name='credits'))

    def launch_game(self):
        self.sm.remove_widget(Game_Menu(name='menu'))
        game = Game()
        game_menu = Menu_UI()
        Window.size = game.size
        engines1.loop = True
        engines1.play()
        return game

    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    GameApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following instruction `self.sm.remove_widget(Game_Menu(name='menu'))` You are creating a new Menu object that has not been added to the ScreenManager, because it has not been added it can not be removed. What you should do is get the same menu, for this we will use the get_screen () method of ScreenManager to get the same Screen through its name and then remove it.

You must replace the previous line with the following lines:

```
menu = self.sm.get_screen('menu')
self.sm.remove_widget(menu)
```

Comment: It worked ! Nice one. But now I get a black screen and nothing else. And the game plays in background. Need to find a way how to make the game visible to a player.

Comment: @DanLambert I can not help you anymore because your code limits me :D

Comment: That's okay. It's on me to figure this one out. Cheers !